# Android, AppBrain AppLift SDK: how to add event handler on interstitial ad click

Tags: android

I have an Android app and I'm adding AppBrain SDK to show AppBrain's offer wall (list of apps advertisied on AppBrain), which I consider less annoying than other types of full-screen ads. I implemented AppBrain's AppLift SDK and it shows the offer wall. I would like to [do something] when a user clicks on one of the ads shown on the offer wall (nothing malicious, just some tracking for statistical purposes). They do have examples on using both regular ads and full-screen ads, but only regular banner ads example shows how to use BannerListener to handle onclick, onshow, etc. The example for interstitial ads does not have anything on the use of BannerListener, and I can't figure out how to tie it to the AdService class which is what's used to serve interstitial ads:

```
    AppBrain.init(this);
    AdService ads = AppBrain.getAds();
    ads.maybeShowInterstitial(this);
```

Their support did not respond to my email, so I thought I'd ask here. Any ideas/comments/suggestions will be greatly appreciated!

UPDATE:

The AppBrain support got back to me and confirmed that there's no way to have an event raised when an interstitial ad is clicked on. Not having control over how the data is collected is a major inconvieience and I might need to switch to the AdMob for interstitials, as they do provide the functionality.